# showDialog barrierDismissible and the return value

Tags: flutter

If I'm trying to get an answer from the user, I might use a dialog and I might want to make it user friendly incase the user wants to cancel. In such a case I'd use barrierDismissible: true (which I think is the default for `showDialog` anyways.)

If I call `showDialog` in that way, and I'm taking its return value, as the answer from the user, how do identify the case where the user clicked on the background to dismiss the dialog. In a case such as this I would want to ignore the return value of `showDialog` rather than think the user intentionally chose not to select or type anything (such as in a TextField).

Answer (score 0):

Seem I've identified the answer with a little experimentation.

showDialog returns null when you dismiss the dialog. If your using a TextField, that text field doesn't give you a null value for an empty input, it gives you a zero length string.

So its easy to identify the 2 different scenarios.